# My update function doesn't return or updated in database and my connection is right findbyidandupdate in mongoose

Tags: node.js

My Update and remove function not working return null to me 
connection to database is right and id is right and create or add anew course details this function run and right

async function updateCourse(id){
           console.log(id);

```
        const course= await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{
            $set: {
                author:'jack',
                isPublished:false
            }
        });
        console.log(course);
        }
```

updateCourse('5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777');

this is the error msg  i accept to return a course object updated it return null

PS D:\Work\mongo-demo> node exercise.js
5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777
(node:8976) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:8976) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Connected to MongoDB....
null